# Is it possible to have an Angular js $http request inside another request?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, angularjs-http

I am trying to send a request in `AngularJS` to get a token for user registration. Once I get the token, I am sending another request using the token to register the user.

However the first request works and I get the token, but the second one does not work.

#### Code

```js
facebookExample.controller('registerController', function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $location) {
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.getToken = function() {
      $http.post('http://you-serve.org/api.php?action=createaccount&format=json&name=' + $scope.data.username + '&email=' + $scope.data.email + '&realname=' +
        $scope.data.firstname + ' ' + $scope.data.lastname +
        '&mailpassword=false&reason=Fun_and_profit&language=en&token').then(
        function(response) {
          return response.data.createaccount.token;
        }
        // End success
        ,
        function() {
          alert('error');
        } // End error 
      ); //End then
    } // End getToken

  $scope.register = function(myToken) {
      $http.post('http://you-serve.org/api.php?    action=createaccount&format=json&name=' +
        $scope.data.username + '&email=' +
        $scope.data.email + '&realname=' +
        $scope.data.firstname + ' ' +
        $scope.data.lastname +
        '&mailpassword=false&reason=Fun_and_profit&language=en&token=' + myToken).then(
        function(response) {
          alert("Registration successful !  You can log in now " + response.data.createaccount.username);
        },
        function(response) {
          alert(response.data.error.info);
        }); //End then
    } //End register


  $scope.signup = function() {
      register(getToken);
    } // End sign up
}); // End controller
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-view ng-controller="registerController" title="Sign Up" view-title="Sign Up" name="login-view">

  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
      </label>


      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="data.email">
      </label>


      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="data.firstname">
      </label>

      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="data.lastname">
      </label>



      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="City" ng-model="data.city">
      </label>




      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Country" ng-model="data.country">
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="register(getToken())">Sign Up</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Anyone know how I can I do this ?

Comment: You can create a local variable, assign the token to the local variable. And then pass it to second http request.

Comment: Since `$http` call is async, you will have to call second request inside **success** of first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain promises (which is what $http returns) by using promise1.then(promise2).

So in your case the correct way to chain getToken and register is:

```
$scope.getToken().then($scope.register)
```

(after you modify the two functions to *return* the $http calls)

**Edit:** (further explanation)

What you are trying to do is called *promise chaining*. Esentially, executing two or more asynchronous operations in sequential order. From the [html5rocks promise tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/):

> ## Queuing asynchronous actions
>
> You can also chain "then"s to run async actions in sequence.
>
> When you return something from a "then" callback, it's a bit magic. If you return a value, the next "then" is called with that value. However, if you return something promise-like, the next "then" waits on it, and is only called when that promise settles (succeeds/fails).

The way this works is that when you return a value from the `Promise` or the `.then()` function, then the next then function in the chain is called with the return value of the `.then()` function or the resolution of the `Promise`, and if the return value is a `Promise`, the chain then waits on this `Promise` to resolve before it continues.

Thus (and remember than $http returns a `Promise` object):

```
function a() {
    return $http.get('...').then(function (response) { return response.data; });
}

function b(data) {
    return $http.get('...'+data).then(function (response) { return response.data; });
}
```

To chain the two functions together, so that `b()` gets called with the result of `a()`, just do this:

```
a().then(b)
```

Do read [the tutorial on `Promise`s](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) to get a better handle on how they work. They are one of the best tools JavaScript has to make asynchronous operations easier to handle.

PS: In your specific case, the code would be:

```
facebookExample.controller('registerController', function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $location) {
  $scope.data = {};

  function getToken() {
    return $http.post('http://you-serve.org/api.php?action=createaccount&format=json&name=' + $scope.data.username + '&email=' + $scope.data.email + '&realname=' + $scope.data.firstname + ' ' + $scope.data.lastname + '&mailpassword=false&reason=Fun_and_profit&language=en&token')
      .then(
        function(response) {
          return response.data.createaccount.token;
        },
        // End success
        function() {
          alert('error');
        } // End error 
      ); //End then
  } // End getToken

  function register(myToken) {
    return $http.post('http://you-serve.org/api.php?action=createaccount&format=json&name=' +
        $scope.data.username + '&email=' +
        $scope.data.email + '&realname=' +
        $scope.data.firstname + ' ' +
        $scope.data.lastname +
        '&mailpassword=false&reason=Fun_and_profit&language=en&token=' + myToken)
      .then(
        function(response) {
          alert("Registration successful !  You can log in now " + response.data.createaccount.username);
        },
        function(response) {
          alert(response.data.error.info);
        }
      ); //End then
  } //End register


  $scope.signup = function() {
    getToken().then(register);
  } // End sign up
}); // End controller
```

Comment: To return the $http calls ? Example ?

Comment: I think @souldreamer means that getToken() should return an object (or other value) that is usable by register()

Comment: Thanks @souldreamer !

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in two ways :

**Method 1 - Normal Way:**

```
$scope.getToken = function() { 
    $http.post().then(function success(response) {
         // call register method here
         $scope.register(response.data.createaccount.token);
    }, function error(reason) {
      // do something
    });
};
```

**Method 2 - Use $watch:**

```
$scope.token = null;

 $scope.getToken = function() { 
        $http.post().then(function success(response) {
             // set the token value here
             $scope.token = response.data.createaccount.token;
        }, function error(reason) {
          // do something
        });
    };

$scope.$watch(function () { return $scope.token;}, 
function (newVal, oldVal) { 

if (newVal !== oldVal) {
   $scope.register(newVal);
}

});
```

Comment: Rabi, thanks for your response. I have done method 1 before. It s the closest to working I got . However still the user is not registered in the database. I m starting to think my error has to do with something other than the requests.